# Sharepoint calculated column based on other columns #NULL! error

Tags: list, sharepoint, calculated-columns

I am trying to add two currency columns in a calculated column but am getting a #NULL! error.

This seems pretty straightforward but its my first time doing this in SharePoint.

SharePoint 2010 with Excel Services available.

Have create List with required columns:

Approved Value column Type = Currency

Pending Value column Type = Currency

Total Value column 
Calculated (calculation based on other columns) 
Type = Currency
Formula: =[Approved Value]+[Pending Value]

The values in other columns are indeed currency, but the Total shows #NULL! for all items.

I can't see anything done incorrectly.

What should I be looking for to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ISBLANK function to previously check if any of the value is null.

Reference: [ISBLANK function](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/ISBLANK-function-983fc90d-3897-43b5-97cc-db36de15fd06?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using NZ(Value, 0)

=NZ([Approved Value],0)+NZ([Pending Value],0)

Though not sure how NULLs ended up in field or why SharePoint couldn't deal with them without this special treatment.